# Picking a random sprite node from an array in Sprite Kit

Tags: arrays, random, sprite-kit

I am trying to create an app in which one of a few objects is randomly placed on the screen wherever you touch. I have my objects a, b, and c and I have them in an array.

```
(NSArray *) gamePieces {

NSArray *things = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", nil];

return things;
}
```

And then my touch method.

```
(void)touchesBegan:(NSArray *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    // code that chooses random object from array

}
```

}

Normally I would put in an `SKSpriteNode` and it would make just that one appear on the screen, but I am looking to randomly select one of many. I'm new to programming and I'm not sure if I'm on the right path. If I am, what needs to go in the touch method? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random item by getting a random index based on the number of elements in the array :

```
int randomIndex = arc4Random() % things.count;
NSString *thing = things[randomIndex];
// do something with thing
```